# Can't figure out how to play sound android cordova

Tags: android, cordova

Background: using android cordova, phonegap-plugin-push, the file plugin, and the media plugin.

I'm trying to play a sound in `/res/raw` when a notification comes in when the app is open.  I figured out how to do it in iOS, but my android code isn't working.  Here it is:

```
mediaUrl = cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "/res/raw/" + data.sound;
alert(mediaUrl)

var media = new Media(mediaUrl, function (e) {
    media.release();
}, function (err) {
    console.log("media err", err);
});
media.play();
```

Unfortunately it is not working.  I tried to set `forceShow` to be true in android, but it won't play the correct sound when the app is open.  So I have to improvise.  I don't want to waste time fiddling with this when the answer is probably obvious to somebody with more experience. Anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem months ago..
My issue was in the path of media file, I had to change it several times until it works.. The trick was the "assets" folder.

```
var sound = new Media("assets/www/sounds/" + fileName);
```

Comment: do you know how I would do it to find sounds that I bundled with my app in `res/raw/`?

Comment: Maybe your path should be something like: '"/android_asset/www/res/raw/filename'. Also I've seen that in some cases the filename was without extension. Have you tried this?